# VLOOKUP with multiple criteria and multiple csv output

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

## I have two tables:

### Table-A

List of regions and road types for each name (used letters for example)

```
Area                               Road Type    Name
Masterton, Carterton               LR           A
Wairarapa                          LR           B
Hamilton, Cambridge                SH           C
Auckland, Christchurch, Wellington LR,S         D
NI                                 SH           E
SI                                 SH           F
NZ                                 SH,LR        G
Kapati, Levin                      LR           H
Manawatu                           LR           I
Napier                             SH           J
Hastings, Havelock North           SH,LR        K
Hawke's bay                        LR           L
Dunedin                            SH           M
Napier                             LR           N
NI                                 LR           O
```

### Table-B

List of towns, provinces and islands (NI = North Island, SI - South Island)

```
Town            Province     Island
Masterton       Wairarapa    NI
Carterton       Wairarapa    NI
Hamilton        Waikato      NI
Cambridge       Waikato      NI
Auckland        Auckland     NI
Christchurch    Canterbury   SI
Wellington      Wellington   NI
Kapati          Kapati Coast NI
Levin           Horowhenua   NI
Napier          Hawke's Bay  NI
Hastings        Hawke's Bay  NI
Havelock North  Hawke's Bay  NI
Dunedin         Otago        SI
```

When you enter a Town into C2; C5, C6, and C7 will `Vlookup` `Table-B` to get the relevant data.

[image]

That's the easy bit.

What I am trying to do now is to get a list of names from Table-A (separated with a semi-colon) where either the town, province or island (from the vlookups) **exists** the in Area column and the Road Type (entered in C3) exists in the Road Type column.

Based on the input above the result would be: **N; L; O**

Can't seem to find an example of a vlookup that would provide the output

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

My boss has hopefully made the solution a little simpler. Instead of the two tables, he has provided a single matrix showing:

```
Email    T1    T2    T3    T4    T5    T6    T7    LR    SH
A        X     X                                   X
B        X           X     X                             X
C              X     X                 X           X     X
D                                X     X     X     X
E                          X     X     X                 X
F        X     X     X                             X     X
```

The T# represent a territory the user is interested in and one or both of LR and SH. So if the user provides a T# and either LH or SH the lookup needs to pick the email addressed where there is an X in the relevant T# column and an X in either LR or SH.

So, based on the table above:

- T3 and LR would result in C, F
- T1 and SH would result in B, F
- T6 and LR would result in C, D

Not sure if this simplifies the solution or not.

Comment: Please enter your data as text and not pictures, you will get an answer much faster if you make it easier for us to answer. See [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the data tables.

Comment: Kia ora from New Plymouth. A lookup function will only ever return one result. If you want to return multiple results and comma-separate them that can't be done with worksheet functions. You'll need VBA to do that and loop over the data multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn, I had a feeling that would be the case. Been a few years since I did VBA but should be fun. Will post the end result if I can work it out :-)

Comment: It seems that the based on the input `Napier`, `LR` the result should be: `N; L; O` instead of `J; L; O`, please confirm. Additionally, could you please clarify what would be the `Road Type` entered in `C3` when the `Town` in `C2` is something like `Christchurch` would it be: `LR`; `S` or ` LR,S` or in the case of `Havelock North` would it be: `SH`; `LR` or `SH,LR`.  I have an answer to your question but need the above information to finish it. Thanks.

Comment: @EEM apologies for the delayed response and thank you for taking a look. You are right the result should be N,L,O. I have updated the OP. I have also added a change from what my boss originally gave me. If you had a solution to the original problem though I would still be keen to know how you solved it.

Comment: Would please also answer this: Additionally, could you please clarify what would be the Road Type entered in C3 when the Town in C2 is something like Christchurch would it be: LR; S or ` LR,S` or in the case of Havelock North would it be: SH; LR or SH,LR. Also it seems as per the new matrix that the road type for "Auckland, Christchurch, Wellington" should be "LR,SH" instead of "LR,S".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *Table A* is located at `A3:D18`, *Table B* is located at `F3:H16` and the input *Town* and *Road Type* and the related *Province, Island* and *Names* are located at `J3:N29`.

To obtain the corresponding *Province* and *Island*, enter this formula in `L4` and `M4` then copy downwards:

```
=VLOOKUP( $J19, $F$3:$H$16, MATCH( L$3, $F$3:$H$3, 0 ), 0 )
```

To obtain the *Names* for the corresponding *Town, Province* and *Island* in one cell separated by `;`, Enter this `Array Formula` in `N4` then copy downwards:

`Array Formulas` must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=CONCATENATE(
IFERROR( INDEX( $D$3:$D$18, AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW($D:$D) / ( ( $D$3:$D$18 <> "" )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $J19, $B$3:$B$18 ) > 0, NA() )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $K19, $C$3:$C$18 ) > 0, NA() ) ), 1 ) ),"N/A"), "; ",
IFERROR( INDEX( $D$3:$D$18, AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW($D:$D) / ( ( $D$3:$D$18 <> "" )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $L19, $B$3:$B$18 ) > 0, NA() )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $K19, $C$3:$C$18 ) > 0, NA() ) ), 1 ) ), "N/A" ), "; ",
IFERROR( INDEX( $D$3:$D$18, AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW($D:$D) / ( ( $D$3:$D$18 <> "" )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $M19, $B$3:$B$18 ) > 0, NA() )
* IFERROR( SEARCH( $K19, $C$3:$C$18 ) > 0, NA() ) ), 1 ) ), "N/A" ) )
```

The formula above returns `N/A` when the combination of *Road Type* and *Town, Province*  or *Island* is not present in *Table A*.

[image]

Suggest to read the following pages for details about the functions used:

[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), 
[MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a),
[CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d), 
[IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611), 
[INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), 
[AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df), 
[ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d), 
[SEARCH, SEARCHB functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495), 
[NA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/na-function-5469c2d1-a90c-4fb5-9bbc-64bd9bb6b47c)